# Regular Expression to capture the last </p> tag and replace it with some text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to capture the final

tag in a string. Here's what I came up with:

```
 /(</p>)$/
```

Is this going to cause any problems in a typical html script that looks like this:

```
<p>Copyright 2010 &copy;</p>
<p>Sanscode</p>
```

It seems to work fine, but since i'm new to regex I was wondering if anyone had any caveats or things for me to note. I am using preg_replace().

Thanks

Comment: [Please don't parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not match, if there are whitespace characters behind the last angel bracket.